# JSON Object extract value

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have this code that return a response from an API provider in the format of JSON Object. Below is the code:

```
public class Authentication {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL ("https://xxxxx.com");
            String encoding = "xxxxxxxxx";
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in   = 
                new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);                                                
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will return a response like this:

```
{
  "accessToken": "0.AQAAAUmdztB3AAAAAAAEkvg",
  "tokenType": "Bearer",
  "expiresIn": 300
}
```

So here is the problem, I'm trying to get the value of accessToken only so that i can use it to make an api call. I've tried this:

```
String loudScreaming = JSONML.toJSONObject("accessToken").getString("accessToken");
```

But it will return null. I've read about Jackson but don't have any idea on how to do it. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are using something different than Jackson. It does not contain JSONML class. Anyway, probably you should add `line` instead of `"accessToken"` as a parameter to `toJSONObject(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Jackson to parse a simple JSON structure. This will do the job

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

String jsondata = "{\"accessToken\":\"0.AQAAAUmdztB3AAAAAAAEkvg\",\"tokenType\":\"Bearer\",\"expiresIn\": 300}"

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsondata);
String accessToken = obj.getJSONObject().getString("accessToken");
```

Comment: @StrikeNeo did you try this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple simple examples showing both how you could use **Jackson** (version 2.4.3) and how you could use **GSON** (version 2.3). These are pretty basic use cases and their documentation shows how versatile both of these libraries are.

```
final String JSON_STRING = "{\n" +
        "  \"accessToken\": \"0.AQAAAUmdztB3AAAAAAAEkvg\",\n" +
        "  \"tokenType\": \"Bearer\",\n" +
        "  \"expiresIn\": 300\n" +
        "}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode jackson = objectMapper.readValue(JSON_STRING, ObjectNode.class);
JsonNode jacksonAccessToken = jackson.get("accessToken");
System.out.println("Jackson accessToken: " + jacksonAccessToken);

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject gsonObject = gson.fromJson(JSON_STRING, JsonObject.class);
JsonElement gsonAccessToken = gsonObject.get("accessToken");
System.out.println("GSON accessToken: " + jacksonAccessToken);
```